# Sonar showing "The main branch of this project is empty" but code is correctly analysed

Tags: azure, .net-core, sonarqube

I need your help to solve my problem with sonar.
I use sonar 8.9 on a server anad azure pipeline to communicate with serveur sonar on a .net core 3.1 project.
Once analysis is finished, i have my errors in my sonar qube server but the tab overview indicates "The main branch of this project is empty"
To analyse my projects i follow the sonarqube tuto : https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/azuredevops-integration/

Can someone help me solve this impediment please ?

Answer (score 0):

It was "only" a size problem. Serveur does not allow too long utl parameters and the ajax call do not respond, so overview and measures pages stay emply.

If it can hel someone !

Answer (score 0):

Posting this here in case someone else struggles with this issue and the other posted solutions don't work.

At least for .Net Core, try disabling, one at a time, your PackageReferences in your project file. I spent 2 days trying to isolate the cause for my dashboard not showing results, and it was because I had a reference to an older RC package in one of my project files.

Specifically `<PackageReference Include="Twilio" Version="7.0.0-rc.1" />`

Updating that reference to the latest version resolved the issue.